# Dudas sobre las suspensiones temporales en el chat

Tags: soporte, moderación, chat, suspensiones-chat

Mi pregunta se basa en una situación que ya había *sufrido* en el pasado, y que hoy ya se ha descontrolado, recibiendo 3 suspensiones consecutivas en el chat. Esto ha causado en mi ciertas preguntas a las que me gustaría conocer su respuesta, ya que no he conseguido encontrarlas en ningún sitio:

- ¿Alguien sabe de que formas puede un comentario ser marcado como inapropiado y provocar su eliminación y la correspondiente suspensión temporal? Es siempre via flag de algún usuario en la sala, o hace algún bot de StackExchange un análisis de todas las salas de chat buscando conductas inapropiadas?
- ¿Pueden los moderadores del sitio levantar un flag a un comentario y eliminarlo sin que se proceda a una votación para validarlo?
- ¿Existe alguna manera de "disputar" una decisión así? Es decir, si considero que la suspensión que he recibido es totalmente incorrecta, injusta, o no ha tenido en cuenta el contexto de la conversación, existe alguna formula de reclamación?

Comment: ¡Caramba! Como moderador en un sitio de Stack puedo ver el historial de reportes, y por tanto los mensajes que se han moderado. El moderador que lo revisa determina si es válido o no. Si lo es, te aplica una suspensión X. Los siguientes reportes van escalando cada vez más los minutos de suspensión. No quién lo reportó ni quién gestionó el reporte. En cualquier caso, parece algo hostil que se te reporten tres mensajes en tan poco tiempo, máxime cuando la conversación iba por temas bastante off topic.

Comment: Puedes leer toooodas las normas y roles del chat en [A guide to moderating chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271267/209901)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> - ¿Alguien sabe de que formas puede un comentario ser marcado como inapropiado y provocar su eliminación y la correspondiente suspensión temporal? Es siempre via flag de algún usuario en la sala, o hace algún bot de StackExchange un análisis de todas las salas de chat buscando conductas inapropiadas?

No me consta que haya ningún bot. En cualquier caso, los reportes siempre pasan por las manos de un moderador, por lo que siempre hay alguna persona consciente de que está lanzándose un reporte.

> - ¿Pueden los moderadores del sitio levantar un flag a un comentario y eliminarlo sin que se proceda a una votación para validarlo?

Sí, los reportes (*flags*) que hace un moderador son aceptados automáticamente. De [A guide to moderating chat -> What tools are available to moderators?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271270/209901):

> moderators can flag a message using the same methods for regular users, however moderator flags are binding meaning the message will instantly be deleted, and the author of the flagged message will be suspended for 30 minutes (if already suspended, the author’s suspension will be extended by 30 minutes). This only applies to spam/offensive flags — custom moderator flags do not automatically delete the message or apply any suspension.

Por tanto, si juntamos esta respuesta con la del primer punto, tenemos que un reporte siempre pasa por las manos de algún moderador: el que reporta, o el que lo revisa.

> - ¿Existe alguna manera de "disputar" una decisión así? Es decir, si considero que la suspensión que he recibido es totalmente incorrecta, injusta, o no ha tenido en cuenta el contexto de la conversación, existe alguna formula de reclamación?

Creo que lo oportuno es hablarlo en Meta. Si no te sientes representado o no te satisface lo que se diga allí (aquí, vaya), siempre puedes contactar con un empleado de Stack Overflow usando el [formulario de Contacto](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) que aparece al pie de cada página.

Comment: Me llegan muchos flags de otros chats pero en cuanto a reportes del chat de SOes ni recuerdo el ultimo que vi (hace mucho). Hoy Pikoh y Trauma fueron baneados sin yo enterarme..

Comment: @lois6b es un poco desastre el sistema, porque todos los chats (menos los de [SO]) cuelgan de la misma red y todos los moderadores vemos los reportes de todo el mundo, con lo que acaba cogiéndolo quién sabe quién. Yo tiendo a ignorar todo lo que no conozca por contexto, pero cada moderador obrará de una manera.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Creo que mas o menos empiezo a aclarar conceptos. Y aunque no las confirman, si que hacen viables ciertas sospechas que tengo :)

Comment: @Pikoh huelga decir que la casuística en este caso ha sido la primera: alguien reportó y alguien aceptó. De entre la mar de moderadores, será difícil saber quién

Comment: @fedorqui eso exactamente es lo que que yo quería saber: si el flag fue levantando automáticamente o por un usuario de la sala. Aparentemente, fue lo segundo

Comment: @Pikoh me equivoqué: he consultado y con la información que yo veo no es posible saber si o bien lo reportó un usuario normal y lo aceptó un moderador, o bien lo reportó un moderador. Siento la confusión, es una sección que no conocía y no resulta demasiado intuitiva.

Comment: @fedorqui si, eso ya me había quedado claro, los moderadores no podéis acceder a esos datos, creo que solo los empleados podrían. Gracias por molestarte de todas maneras ;)

Answer (score 4):

Creo que [@fedorqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/83/fedorqui) respondió la pregunta perfectamente! Déjame añadir una nota.

#### ¿Existe alguna manera de "disputar" una decisión así?

¡Sí, puedes! El mejor lugar para eso sería MSE o MSOes, dependiendo de la comunidad con la que quieras discutir un problema. Antes de hacer una pregunta, consulta la publicación de MSE "[Should any Meta post that calls out a user by name be deleted, not just downvoted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289909/274323)".

Creo que es muy importante discutir estos temas con la comunidad. De manera regular, son los usuarios de la comunidad de SOes los que deciden si un mensaje debe marcarse y los moderadores (o usuarios con +10k de reputación) los que revisan las banderas. Significa que si hay un malentendido en una de las partes, se debe discutir entre las personas que han participado en la situación. De lo contrario, podrías enfrentarte al mismo problema una y otra vez.

---

A lot of thanks to [@Pikoh](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15301/pikoh) for the translation!

---

I think, [@fedorqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/83/fedorqui) answered the question perfectly! Let me just add one note.

#### ¿Existe alguna manera de "disputar" una decisión así?

Yes, you can! The best place for that would be either MSE or MSOes, depends on with which community you want to discuss an issue. Before asking a question, please look at a MSE post "[Should any Meta post that calls out a user by name be deleted, not just downvoted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289909/274323)".

I think it's very important to discuss such issues with the community. On regular basis those are users of the SOes community who decide if a message should be flagged and the moderators (or 10k users) who review the flags. It means if there is a misunderstanding on one of the parts it should be discussed among those people who have participated in the situation. Otherwise you might face the same problem again and again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I mainly opened this question because I felt that the 3 bans received were not fair (although of course I may be wrong) and wanted to know what was the best way to raise it. Of course, i can't and won't name any user, mainly because I'm not able to know who raised or approved the flag, but now from the answers i get that i should make a post here exposing the facts, in order to ask the community how to face this problems :)