# Discusión sobre mi suspensión y estas en general

Tags: discusión, soporte, moderación, suspensiones-chat

**Edición 28/06: Entiendo que el consenso es de no usar palabras malsonantes, pero por favor, ir a buscarlas a propósito y reportar palabras de hace 20 horas me parece un tanto excesivo.**

**Situación:**
Hoy he recibido una suspensión de una hora en el chat por el siguiente mensaje en esta conversación:

> **Persona A:** Si, se puede vivir con 680€. Yo he vivido con 500€ en  Barcelona varios meses del 2001 xD
>
> **Yo:** con 500€ en 2001 se hacía más que ahora
>
> **Persona B:** era un poco dificil tener 500€ en 2001
>
> **Yo:** díselo a **A**, puto

Quien quiera leerla al completo la puede buscar en el chat, pues se trata de una cita literal.

Tengo varias quejas: unas generales que me parecen cuanto menos vergonzosas y otras por las razones y la forma de esta suspensión concreta.

**Quejas generales:**

- **NO** se da el motivo de la suspensión. Me he enterado de la misma por la persona que me ha reportado.
- La persona que ha valorado si el flag era correcto o no era de una comunidad externa en inglés. Cosa que me parece cuanto menos ridícula.
- No te dicen quién te ha reportado o quién ha dado por válido el motivo de la suspensión por lo que no puedes discutirla en ningún momento.

**Mi suspensión en concreto:**

Pese a que la ambigüedad de las normas puede justificar la suspensión considero que no es justo por lo siguientes motivos:

- Las 2 personas de la conversación las considero de *confianza* y es la razón por la que entiendo que puedo dirigirme a ellos de ese modo.
- He escrito *puto* como podía haber escrito el típico *cabrón* (consideré que puto suena más en broma), *gentuzo* o inserte la chorrada de turno que ud. utiliza. Creo que todos lo hemos usado en la vida y también en el chat, yo mismo previamente y hacia mi, siempre entre personas de confianza.
- Era la hora de comer y estábamos los 4 gatos de siempre, no había nadie que pudiese malinterpretar la frase. Y si alguien que entra a posteriori la lee, es porque ha leído todo por lo que ya tiene el contexto de la misma y no creo que le sorprenda.
- Por lo que ha dicho la persona *insultada*, no le ha molestado y ha entendido el uso que pretendía darle a la palabra.
- La persona que me ha reportado era ajena a la conversación. ¿Ahora pueden decidir 3º cómo me dirijo o me dejo de dirigir a otros que entiendo de mi confianza?

**ACLARACIÓN**: En ESPAÑA, o hasta dónde yo sé en mi entorno, *PUTO* no es un insulto y nadie en su sano juicio lo utilizaría para insultar, básicamente porque se reirían de ti. (A diferencia de la versión terminada en a)

Comment: Creo injusta tu suspensión y votaría por quitártela. Dicho lo cual, ¿qué otro objetivo tiene la pregunta? No sé cómo supiste quién validó el reporte ni quién lo hizo (no son datos públicos) pero en cualquier caso el moderador en cuestión (eso puedo verlo porque también soy moderador) no tiene conocimiento de castellano (hay una lista para intentar repartirse los reportes de idiomas diferentes al inglés), por lo que estaría bien contactar con él. Dado que tienes datos solo al alcance de moderadores, supongo que ya está todo en sus manos.

Comment: Yo estoy de acuerdo en la suspensión, estas en un sitio donde se moderan las conductas de la comunidad y ello tambien conlleva a los chats. Fuese o no de confianza la persona a la que te diriges los chats son de la comunidad por lo que deberias evitar groserias ya que en nuestro idioma existen mejores frases, asi que si no deseas posibles suspensiones usa un chat personal.

Comment: Por otro lado nunca se obliga a indicar quien hizo el reporte del mismo modo que no se obliga a señalar si uno da un downvote porque él que recibe la sanción/downvote puede tomar represalias. Ademas el reporte en si no genera la sanción, lo tuvo que aceptar un moderador diamantado o alguien que tengas los superpoderes de suspensión.

Comment: @eyllanesc No existe el concepto de chat personal en el entorno SO, por lo que la suspensión sería aplicable del mismo modo... Y lo que me preocupa no es quién reporta si no que no te dicen el **por qué**.

Comment: @AsieR_2 cuando señalo chat personal me refiero a un chat de FB, Telegram, Whatsapp, etc. En conclusion si vas a usar vulgaridades no uses los chats de SO.

Comment: @AsieR_2 Si no se te señalaron el motivo de la suspensión lo puedes preguntar en META, para eso es este lugar. Seguramente quién te aplico la sanción escribira en algun momentos el motivo de porque la aplico, asi que solo es cuestion de esperar ya que cualquier usuario puede reportar pero no todos podemos sancionar.

Comment: @eyllanesc No señalaron el motivo, me lo dijo la persona que me reportó. Si no me llega a decir nada... sorpresa. En cualquier caso me parece ridícula la normativa. Pa eso poned un bloqueador de palabras y ya está. Si vamos a actuar como robots dejadles a ellos el trabajo.

Comment: @AsieR_2 1) Yo no discuto que es malo que no te indicaron el motivo, al contrario estoy a tu favor en ese punto, pero se puede remediar, solo es cuestion de esperar. 2) La regla existe desde los inicios de SO porque aqui se espera que seamos respetuosos con todos, que evitemos las vulgaridades, y todos podemos reportar si un usuario no cumple con las reglas como tú lo has hecho.

Comment: @AsieR_2 [cont.] ¿Qué ganamos con aceptar vulgaridades? nada, ¿Qué perdemos si las aceptamos? pues puede traer discusiones, malentendidos, etc. Asi que aceptar vulgaridades solo trae desventajas. Y como ya sabes mi recomendación es que las evites, o usas tu chat personal para ello.

Comment: @AsieR_2 En SOen existen bots que alertan sobre el uso de vulgarimos en las preguntas, respuestas y comentarios en los chats.

Comment: @eyllanesc pues nunca han saltado o al menos nunca se me ha comunicado nada. Y las 'vulgaridades' son parte del lenguaje común, se usan y se usarán siempre en el chat, eso te lo garantizo y ya no lo digo solo por mi.

Comment: @eyllanesc y con este sistema maravilloso de reportes podría suspender ahora mismo a 20 personas si me diese la gana.

Comment: @AsieR_2 1) las vulgaridades existen y existiran por siempre(desgraciadamente en mi opinión), pero SO no es el lugar adecuado para usarlas ya que recibiras una sanción. 2) Un reporte no genera sanción a perse, sino te invito a que reportes mis comentarios :-) y veras si me suspenden. Hay alguien con los suficientes poderes y criterios para distinguir si el comentario reportado atenta contra las reglas de SO.

Comment: @eyllanesc Un admin que no habla mi idioma no es ni de lejos un persona con criterio para banear, otra cosa ridícula.

Comment: @AsieR_2 yo no sé quien te sanciono. Si es una persona que no habla español entonces eso es malo, pero ello no quita que debes evitar las vulgaridades aqui. Como te das cuenta estoy de acuerdo con: 1) El mensaje deberia explicar la causa de la sanción 2) Si se va a sancionar por cuesiones idiomaticas el moderador debe hablar español, lo que no estoy de acuerdo contigo: El uso vulgaridades en SO por cualquier motivo.

Comment: @eyllanesc Pues me parece ridículo que cuando la mayoría los usan (sin pasarse en ningún caso) unos pocos puedan moderar el lenguaje general en un sitio de *todos*. Pero esto no va cambiar y mi opinión es irrelevante por lo que lo dejamos por aquí.Todo seguirá igual, caerán bans random, y todos felices.

Comment: @AsieR_2 no se necesita hablar un idioma exacto al tuyo para saber que **PUTO** es una palabra vulgar, sea cual sea el uso o el contexto. El que otros lo hagan no te da el salvoconducto para hacer lo mismo, para eso existen los lineamientos de la comunidad. ¿Es molesto que se apliqué la ley sólo a unos cuantos? Sí, lo es, pero para evitarte eso, simplemente cuida tu vocabulario.

Comment: No eres un usuario nuevo, pero para refrescarte te comparto. [Valores fundamentales](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/key-values) - [Código de conducta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/conduct) - [Conducta esperada de los usuarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con la suspensión ya que va en contra de las reglas de uso del chat, justo como lo pone @Rubén en su respueta. Aunque al momento veo que en el chat hay [468 comentarios con la misma palabra](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=puto&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=newest) y no sé si a alguien ya lo hayan suspendido antes, es posible que sean casos de los cuales ni nos enteramos

Comment: Comparto una [Guía sobre la Moderación en el Chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271267/a-guide-to-moderating-chat) (en inglés). Espero, pueda esclarecer algunos puntos importantes sobre esta discusión.

Comment: Pues me plantearé cuando no esté en caliente borrar la cuenta. Buen finde a todos.

Comment: @AsieR_2 no lo tomes a mal, aunque tengas votos negativos en tu publicación, hay 6 que son positivos, personas que piensan que tu veto fue innecesario. Estás dando tu opinión sobre un tema: ¿Es correcto o no es correcto esto? Y la comunidad en meta se encarga de responderte, ¿cómo lo hacen? con los votos, que precisamente cumplen su función. Los votos negativos no significan que tu opinión no valga nada, simplemente que no la comparten. Tómalo como un consejo y como tú mismo mencionas, tómalo con cabeza fría, y recuerda: [...](http://static.t13.cl/images/sizes/1200x675/1459198726-meme.jpg)

Comment: Y ahora acabo de recibir un negativo en una pregunta de hace un año y pico (en SOes). Pues eso, a seguir hablando igual esta que me baneen si no cierro antes la cuenta, esto es de chiste.

Comment: @AsieR_2 Yo tambien he recibido votos negativos cuando opino, es una mala costumbre pero que se puede hacer, es un costo que tenemos que pagar porque no somos un sitio perfecto, en esos momentos tomo un respiro y digo que mi pregunta/respuesta es buena para soportar un downvote ruidoso :-)

Comment: Sí, pero es irónico recibir un voto de la gente 'formal' y que respeta las normas :)

Comment: @AsieR_2 No somos perfectos pero lo pretendemos asi que si es posible ayudar a respetar las reglas lo haremos, pero al sistema imperfecto no se puede ni debe identificar el downvote ya por motivos discutidos anteriormente, se espera que si una pregunta/respuesta es buena los votos ruidosos positivos o negativos no afecten al total de votos

Comment: @eyllanesc Es una pregunta de hace casi 1 año...  Eso ya no se mueve.

Comment: @AsieR_2 No lo creo, si tu pregunta es buena y comun deberias recibir upvotes cada cierto tiempo, quizas el título de tu pregunta no es general y por lo tanto es dificil de encontrar, no he publicado preguntas en SO pero si respuestas y te digo que he recibido muchos votos a publicaciones antiguas, ademas que observe que lo mismo sucedio con la pregunta asociada.

Comment: @AsieR_2 Ademas cada cierto tiempo reviso mis respuestas más valoradas(no necesariamente son las que tienen mayor puntaje) y las mejoro, lo mismo intento hacerlo con las preguntas ya que ahora tengo más conocimiento que antes. Quizas pudieses hacer lo mismo tú para que tu pregunta sea mejor valorada.

Comment: @eyllanesc da igual, esto se va del tema, bastante ruido hay ya.

Comment: @AsieR_2 tu introduciste el tema :-)

Comment: @eyllanesc Ya, pero ahora ya no estamos discutiendo ni si quiera sobre los votos 'iregulares'? no sé como llamarlos. Si no que de si respuestas/preguntas viejas reciben votos con el tiempo.

Comment: Y dejad de usar las ':)' porque no sé vosotros pero a mi en temas serios me parecen una burla.

Comment: @AsieR_2 Termino con esto porque nos estamos alejando del tema: los votos irregulares existen y existiran, es ruido, y como se evitan las consecuencias del ruido pues teniendo un gran tráfico. Creo que he sido serio en mis comentarios, los ":-)" no son burla, si consideras que te ofendi te pido disculpas y no lo usare contigo, bye.

Comment: @eyllanesc Al igual que mi *puto*, y aquí estamos...

Comment: @AsieR_2 no tienen punto de comparación, adios, respira y calmate

Comment: @Shaz ¿Por qué? ¿Por usar una expresión que no buscaba herir ni hirió al receptor? "No queremos personas así en este sitio", dijo quien no me conoce de nada y jamás ha compartido tiempo en el chat conmigo.

Comment: @AsieR_2 ni me interesa conocer a alguien que responde de esa manera (lo digo por todos los demás comentarios). Si no te gusta como funciona la comunidad ni su reglamento, la puerta está abierta.

Comment: Poco he dicho para cómo se ha tratado el tema y a mi.

Comment: @Rubén Esos mensajes no son míos, quizás deberías leer un poco más antes de acusar.

Comment: A ver si los que hacen todo esto por molestar sois gente como tú. Yo he dejado claro mi descontento con dicha acción que me parece enfermiza. Eso no quita, que vaya a respetar la decisión, en mi opinión desacertada, de la mayoría.

Comment: Porque una cosa es marcar el contenido como ofensivo si te parece estando en el chat y otra es no ser partícipe del mismo y dedicarte a buscar palabras solo por reportar.

Comment: Disculpa si mal interpreté tu edición, corrijo: Las repuestas en nombre de los moderadores ♦ y del CM son **anteriores** al momento que refieres como "hace 20 horas" . ¿Por qué insistes en defender el uso de lenguaje soez en el [chat] y porque anuncias que se está usando? Parece que lo haces con toda intención de llamar la atención a las publicaciones con dicho lenguaje Ref. [¿Qué es el efecto Meta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4052/65) (nota por error en la corrección cambié una palabra que no debía)

Comment: Y en el código de conducta de la red en ningún momento se establece que no se pueda usar lenguaje vulga/soez si este no es ofensivo.

Comment: Yo veo complementa mente natural el que se vean los comentarios de las últimas horas para enterarse de lo que se ha está discutiendo y también complementamente normal y hasta aplaudible el que si se encuentra algo que no debe ser se reporte. Nótese estoy hablando de una las últimas horas, no de ir al recorrer el chat desde el primer día.

Comment: El código de conducta dice textualemente "No toleramos ninguna frase que pueda ofender o apartar a las personas por motivos de raza, sexo, orientación sexual o religión, y estos son solo algunos ejemplos. En caso de duda, simplemente no lo hagas."

Comment: Está claro que la búsqueda se ha hecho a propósito con ese fin, no es casual. Dudo que nadie suba taaaan arriba.

Comment: Pues ya está, algo malsonante no tiene por qué ofender per se, de hecho, se puede hacer mucho más daño sin necesidad de usar dichas palabras.

Comment: Además para clarificar están los FAQ: [¿Está permitido en los sitios de SE el lenguaje soez (maldiciones, groserías, lenguaje vulgar, palabras malsonantes)?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4217/65).

Comment: Eso se puso después de mi y no menciona al chat directamente.

Comment: @AsieR_2 El original fue publicado en el 2009. En cuanto al chat, lee esto [Are expletives allowed in SE chat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126017/289691) que es del 2012.

Comment: @Rubén Ahí en ningún momento se prohíben. Lo que aquí se ha escrito difiere muuuuucho con lo que pone ahí.

Answer (score 20):

Discutimos esto entre todos los moderadores del sitio, y también seguimos buscando ayuda al respecto. Esperamos noticias sobre por qué fue el ban directo, sin siquiera consultarlo con alguno de nosotros (nos enteramos después que la suspensión fue emitida).

Estamos todos de acuerdo en algo, tratemos de suavizar el lenguaje del chat.

Coincido con fedorqui en que esto es como una plaza. Sin embargo, cuando llevo a mi hijo a la plaza, trato de suavizar lo que digo, ya que no se quienes están alrededor o escuchando.

Vamos a conversar con los CM y también con los otros moderadores para tratar de evitar este tipo de cosas en el futuro. Creo que todos los usuarios del chat tienen un periodo de aprendizaje, y que los usuarios con antigüedad deben dar el ejemplo.

Lo que proponemos es evitar totalmente cualquier tipo de palabra, expresión, gif o imagen que pueda llevar a mal entender algo. Si dudas, no lo hagas.

El chat puede ser divertido sin necesidad de menospreciar ninguna clase de persona por ningún tipo de condición.

Nuestra propuesta incluye agregar esto también al código de conducta, para que se sepa cómo debemos comportarnos también allí.

Sin embargo, esto no implica que alguien va a ser automáticamente baneado por usar la palabra *puto*. Simplemente, evitémosla.

Como también evitemos otro regionalismos que puedan llegar a pasar por una "mala palabra".

No vamos a poder evitar decir cosas que a otros le suenen mal, no hay forma. Si algún mexicano habla del "dulce de cajeta", siento decirles que acá, en argentina, decir cajeta no está bien visto (es una referencia a la vagina, muy mal sonante); sin embargo, no vamos a poder banear a alguien por decir eso.

Entonces, simplemente, evitemos las palabras que sabemos que en otros países pueden caer mal.

Como nota al margen, el moderador que tomo el flag hizo una traducción automática a *"tell this to fucking* ", y parecía mal sonante (lo cual es), pero entiendo que para un español, es correcto (y esa no sería la traducción que buscamos).

Comment: Me encantó tu respuesta, y solo me deja con una duda. Dices que evitemos la palabra p*to, pero habrá quien no la evite (por desconocimiento de las reglas del chat, porque su región no es una palabra altisonante, qué se yo...), ¿qué va a pasar en esos casos? Ahora surge la palabra p*uto, pero la siguiente semana sale *pendejo*, y así una nueva con el paso del tiempo, ¿me explico? Será un tema de nunca acabar si es que nos queremos meter en camisas de 11 varas

Comment: Exacto!!! no hay una solucion.. solo tratar de evitarla y enseñar a los nuevos a tratar de manterner el idioma neutro. Tenemos montones de palabras zonales, yo puedo decir pajita sin problema, los de mexico pueden decir cajeta sin problemas. Y vamos a encontrar montones mas.. aca son todos boludos... en mexico todos pendejos.. en españa todos putos.. y estan mal para otras regiones.. no hay forma de evitarlo.. pero si, de ir enseñando y no tomar medidas drasticas al respecto.. solo evitarlo...

Comment: Considero desde mi particular punto de vista que, a este tema se le dio mucho más importancia de la que merecía. Digo, bastaba con explicar el ban, hacer saber que existe un código de conducta, reglas en el chat y las implicaciones que esto conlleva si no se respeta y ya, pero me agrada tu postura y veo que en general es la postura que todos los presentes en esta charla tienen. Un usuario con una inconformidad revoloteó más de lo que pensé en el momento que vi su publicación

Comment: Hace unos días levante un reporte para la atención de un moderador ♦ acerca la reversión de una edición para "censurar" el lenguaje soez en la que incluí como referencia el FAQ en Meta SE en el que se indica que **bajo ninguna circunstancia** se permite este lenguaje. En el mismo se mencionan las excepciones que por limitaciones de espacio no repetiré aquí. Este reporte fue rechazado lo cual es incorrecto, como he dicho previamente, el FAQ señala que **bajo ninguna circunstancia** se permite este lenguaje. Nota he traducido el FAQ en cuestión y otro post sobre el tema, ver [tag:lenguaje-soez].

Comment: Aprovecho la ocasión para solicitar que remuevas el lenguaje soez de tu propia publicación, me refiero en específico a la palabra que que se sugiere simplemente evitar.

Comment: Regresando al punto del reporte, no revertí yo mismo la reversión para evitar caer en una guerra de ediciones.

Comment: @Rubén (repito aquí lo que dije en tu publicación en Meta SE) hay una distinción importante entre [_usar_ y _mencionar_](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distinci%C3%B3n_entre_uso_y_menci%C3%B3n) una palabra.  Aquí es claramente mención y no uso, por lo tanto no es en contra de ninguna regla de SE. Tener una discusión sobre una palabra sin mencionar esa palabra solo nos mete en líos, obligándonos a hacer contorsiones lingüísticas para evitar mencionarla. Este publicación es un ejemplo perfecto del caso donde la publicación [_necesita_](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4220/693) la palabra.

Comment: @terdon No, no es así. La distinción entre usar y mencionar no es relevante en este caso ya que no hacía falta mencionar la palabra y menos aún hace falta que esta continue a la vista pues en el historial de revisiones se puede ver. El asunto toral no es si la palabra en cuestión es o no es lenguaje soez, y si lo fuera ello está fuera de tema en un sitio sobre programación y del sitio sobre su funcionamiento.  Afortunadamente está [spanish.se] donde se puede realizar preguntas/respuestas sobre lenguaje soez en español.

Comment: @Rubén lo siento, pero para mi mencionar la palabra es absolutamente necesario dado que toda la discusión aquí es sobre esta palabra. Tener que buscar en el historial para entender en tema principal no me parece lógico. Es precisamente por este tipo de casos que hay la excepción en la publicación que mencionaste del Meta SE. No podemos no mencionar una palabra cuando ella es el tema en cuestión! Y, en todo caso, hay precedente bien establecido por _mencionar_ cualquier palabra cuando se trata de discusiones lingüísticas como esta. La mención solo es prohibida en los títulos de preguntas.

Comment: @terdon Te dejo una referencia [Copiar lenguaje soez y palabras obscenas en Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4219/65) la cual es una traducción de [Copying profanities and obscene words on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172734/289691)

Comment: @Rubén si, ya la conozco y además la mencioné en un comentario anterior (la palabra "necesario" es un enlace a precisamente este respuesta). Y estoy totalmente de acuerdo: este es un caso donde mencionar la palabra es necesario.

Comment: @terdon Ese artículo menciona que como no necesario los casos, aunque resulte poco práctico, que se puedan consultar en el historial que en este caso además está disponible en los reportes accesibles para los usuarios con >10k.

Comment: @Rubén lo siento, pero no. Dice que no era necesario en aquel caso específico porque el OP había dado un enlace directo a la edición donde aparecía la palabra. No dice nada del historial y en todo caso no hacía ninguna generalisación de este tipo. La única generalisación era "*si no es necesario, no la uses. Si es necesario, no te preocupas y usala*". Pues, en este respuesta que se trata específicamente de esta palabra, ¡es claramente necesario! No mencionarla mientras estamos hablando sobre ella me parece absurdo.

Comment: @gbianchi Considerando que tu respuesta es un concenso entre los moderadores diamantados que se va a hacer en concreto, por ejemplo Phi en 
[este comentario](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4207/discusi%c3%b3n-sobre-mi-suspensi%c3%b3n-y-estas-en-general#comment16322_4207) señalo que habia 468 comentarios con esa palabra, revisando en el momento de este  comentario veo que ha aumetado a [491 comentarios](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=puto&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=newest).

Comment: @gbianchi si los reporto ¿serian válidos a tu criterio?

Comment: @eyllanesc https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/30872?m=50843091#50843091

Comment: @AsieR_2 No entiendo del porqué de tu enlace, que un usuario diga que no abusen de algo no implica nada, estoy consultando con un moderador para que me de su opinión y asi evitar abusos. Que un punto no te guste a ti no implica que no sea lo correcto.

Comment: @eyllanesc Pues que no sé si fuiste tú o no, pero nos hemos encontrado eso al llegar al chat esta mañana.

Comment: Lo de buscar la palabra a propósito para reportarla me parece ya...

Comment: @AsieR_2 Yo no he buscado palabras para reportar y dañar a alguien, esa no es mi actitud. Yo solo quiero dar un seguimiento a este tema, se entiende que usar esa groseria sabiendo que no es aceptable ni  necesario aquí despues de la gran discusión que se tuvo en torno a tu suspensión haría que se evite su uso pero parece que no, asi que mi consulta es concreta ¿Qué hacemos para evitar su uso?, ya se advirtio que no lo hagan y aun así lo siguen haciendo.

Comment: @AsieR_2 Yo no voy a reportar comentarios antiguos porque en mi criterio considero que eso fue un error ya que el tema no estuvo claro, pero que lo sigan haciendo eso sí es el colmo. Si para mejorar el sitio tengo que hacer una búsqueda lo haré ya que no infrinjo ninguna regla y es mi derecho en SO. La moderación es uno de los pilares más importantes del sitio, es lo que hizo quedarme en este sitio respecto a otros.

Comment: @eyllanesc Allá tú, eres libre de hacerlo, pero el ambiente que se está creando por algo que no había molestado nunca nos va a salir muy caro a todos.

Comment: Aunque para la discusión no tenga importancia me gustaría matizar una cosa para poner las cosas en su justo valor, esas busquedas son de todos los chats, una búsqueda solo en el chat SOes devuelve 195 resultados, que son menos de la mitad de lo que se está diciendo aquí. También es verdad que hay otras palabras pero se usan bastante menos.

Comment: @eyllanesc sabes perfectamente que la palabra no se usa con una intención ofensiva ni ofende a nadie. Reportarla da más problemas que no hacerlo y dejarlo pasar, vamos a acabar peleados unos con otros por la falta de tolerancia de unos pocos.

Comment: @Aritzbn si evitarias tus groserias no habría problema, yo solo voy a reportarlo si los considero necesario, la comunidad y las personas con los poderes necesarios decidira si es correcto o no.

Comment: @blonfu mi pregunta no va en el sentido de la cantidad,  como ya señale en otro comentario si es una publicación antigua no la reportaré, si en cambio es nueva eso si lo hare cuando lo considere necesario. Si no es en el chat de SOes entonces el reporte lo tomara otros moderadores o usuarios con los poderes necesarios que decidiran, aquí al final los moderadores somos la comunidad, mi reporte no genera ningun efecto inmediato. Si se considera mi reporte inadecuado entonces será rechazado y sufrire las consecuencias por ello.

Comment: Solo he pedido un punto de vista de un moderador, ¿Qué hay de malo en ello? (Tambien invito a otros moderadores a responder a [mi pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4207/discusi%c3%b3n-sobre-mi-suspensi%c3%b3n-y-estas-en-general/4223?noredirect=1#comment16473_4223)).

Comment: @eyllanesc desde mi punto de vista tu actitud es bastante más grosera que mis palabras, pero no quiero discutir sobre este tema. En el chat siento que estoy en un entorno de confianza y estoy seguro de que no ofendo a la gente con la que me relaciono. Hasta hace poco esto no era ningún problema, si quieres ofenderte por algo como usar la palabra puto,que en muchos significados no tiene una connotación negativa,sino ponderativa, tal y como lo explica el diccionario de la RAE. Ahora bien, si quieres tomarlo como algo inapropiado o malsonante estás en tu derecho, pero ambos sabemos que no es así.

Comment: @eyllanesc ya sé que no trata de la cantidad, por eso he dicho que no cambia nada en lo que se está discutiendo. De todas formas he metido la pata porque buscado la palabra en másculino y femenino si nos acercamos a esos valores

Comment: @Aritzbn Si *ambos sabemos que no es así* no estaría toda esta discusión, asi que no estoy de acuerdo con tu opinión. Mi posición es clara.

Comment: De todas formas, @eyllanesc si tienes algún problema conmigo o con mi vocabulario, te invito a que abramos una sala de chat y lo discutamos como adultos para así tratar de entendernos, que me expliques tu punto de vista y por qué consideras que lo que hago es incorrecto, desde mi punto de vista creo que estás juzgando la palabra sin tener en cuenta el contexto.

Comment: @Aritzbn Okay, abre un chat y pásame el enlace.

Comment: @eyllanesc aquí está: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95478/eyllanescaritzbn

Answer (score 13):

De acuerdo a [Are expletives (cursing, swear words or vulgar language) allowed on SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22232/289691) no se permite el lenguaje vulgar, maldiciones, groserías. Si se persiste en el uso estos se se aplicará una suspensión temporal.

Incluso existe al menos dos hilos específicos para el chat, [Toward a philosophy of Chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270587/289691) donde se hace mención que existen suspensiones automáticas que van en incrementos de 30 minutos y [Are expletives allowed in SE chat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126017/289691) donde también se habla de suspenciones a partir de 30 minutos.

Es válido estar inconforme con lo anterior y expresar dicha inconformidad pero mientras esto no se discuta y se establezcan las bases para dar ejemplos del lenguaje en cuestión debería evitarse el uso de estas mismas expresiones, particularmente en Meta pues se corre el riesgo de ser suspendido temporalmente nuevamente.

En cuanto a las alternativas, usa otro espacio que no esté sujeto a estas reglas.

Relacionado

- [Dudas sobre las suspensiones temporales en el chat](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3947/65)

Comment: **Si se persiste**, no persistí.

Comment: @AsieR_2 había pasado por alto de que existen suspensiones automáticas, quizás tu asumiste que sólo una persona flaggeo tu post, pero pudo haber más. Por otro lado la palabra en cuestión además de ser considerada vulgaridad algunos la consideran lenguaje homofóbico, por ejemplo, fuera de este espacio está el caso de las multas a Federación Mexicana de Futbol porque los asistentes gritaban esa palabra en partidos de la FIFA.

Comment: No hubo más, no había más gente y vino un mod de The Workplace a eliminar el comentario y banear. Y las valoraciones individuales que puede hacer una persona de una palabra jamás pueden ser válidas en un entorno común por razones más que obvias, todo puedo ofender a alguien.

Comment: Entonces parte de tu post es confuso, pero lo dicho, es valido estar inconforme y expresar la inconformidad...mientras tanto evita usar ese vocabulario en estos espacios.

Comment: A Meta no vengo a *desahogarme*, para eso no perdería tanto tiempo.

Comment: @Rubén no me consta que haya flags automáticos en el chat

Comment: En cuanto al uso de _puto_, en España no tiene para nada la connotación que tiene en ciertas zonas de Hispanoamérica. Por ello, que @asier_2 de España la utilice con otra persona de este mismo país excluye esa connotación. Con un idioma tan diverso y extendido, tener en cuenta todas las connotaciones sería una locura. ¿No podemos decir concha, por ejemplo?

Comment: @fedorqui es que es eso, la gente de España no siente molestia y son los que han dado positivos mientras que en latino américa es a la inversa. Y me parece en cierto modo injusto que en base a su *mayoría* (lo son en SOes no me cabe duda) el lenguaje quede capado al uso que allí se hace.

Comment: @AsieR_2 yo estoy de acuerdo contigo y no soy de España :) para mi siempre se debe respetar la presunción de inocencia, que si en algún momento digo algo no es por insultar y las personas que se ofenden abran un poco su mente y se den cuenta que si una cosa significa algo aquí no signiica lo mismo allá. Por ejemplo a mi no me gustaría que me suspendan por decir "Tengo ganas de comer unos buenos [_chochos_](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lupinus_mutabilis)"

Comment: @KacosPro pues eso entraría en lo que aquí llaman *vulgaridad* por lo que me temo que sí sería motivo de ban...

Comment: @KacosPro muy buen ejemplo! En España esa frase sonaría horrible, pero en el contexto que das se ve que en México es una cosa diferente.

Comment: @fedorqui es una legumbre que se come en Ecuador, donde nací  imagínate mi sorpresa al enterarme lo que significa en España

Comment: @KacosPro estoy de acuerdo que ciertas frases tienen significados distintos en cada pais que pueden causar confusión, pero la frase que uso el OP dista de concha ni chochos. IMHO prefiero usar frases del español que todos compartimos para evitar malentendidos.

Comment: @fedorqui la palabra puto es malsonante en todos los países. En España no tendrá una tan mala connotación como en otros países, pero sigue siendo malsonante.

Comment: @Alvaro no dije que no lo fuera, sino que en España no tiene la connotación que en otros países. Si estuviera hablando en confianza con algunos usuarios españoles en una hora tranquila del chat (los 4 gatos que comenta Asier), vería normal dejar caer un _mamón_ o similar. Palabras malsonantes pero que según el contexto tienen una connotación diferente. Creo que se está valorando en términos absolutos una palabra, lo cual es un error grave pues las palabras no son nada sin contexto.

Comment: @fedorqui el chat es público. Que un usuario esté teniendo una conversación con 4 o 5 personas en ese momento no quita que haya 20 usuarios en la sala y que esa conversación vaya a estar disponible todo el tiempo. Ese “no había nadie” no excusa el lenguaje malsonante e inapropiado.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Si alguien lee el chat completo a posteriori tiene más contexto que cualquiera que haya leído mi 'post' de Meta.

Comment: @Alvaro resulta un poco curioso que se priorice la potencial visibilidad de algo sobre el impacto de la acción de reportar sin preaviso a un usuario del sitio. Es decir, parece que se priorice a un usuario hipotético sobre un usuario existente. Sobre eso escribo en [mi respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4214/83).

Answer (score 12):

Muchas gracias a [@Alvaro Montoro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/250/alvaro-montoro) por la traducción.

---

Creo que la [respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4223/10) de [@gbianchi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/324/gbianchi)’s cubre la pregunta a la perfección. Sólo me gustaría añadir algunas ideas más.

#### La sala de chat es un lugar público

Aunque uno pueda ver la sala de chat como un paseo con un amigo en un parque solitario, es más como hablar a otra persona en un autobús lleno de gente. Eso significa que incluso si uno habla a un amigo en una sala de chat, todo el mundo escucha la conversación y puede no gustarle lo que se dijo o tomarlo de una manera diferente.

#### Todos los moderadores y usuarios con más de 10k ven los reportes

Stack Exchange es una red extensa con 175 comunidades, cientos de moderadores y muchos usuarios con 10k de reputación. ¡Todos ellos que estén usando el chat en ese momento ven el reporte! Eso es mucha gente. El sistema está diseñado de una manera para que los reportes se procesen lo más rápido posible.

#### Los usuarios que procesan los reportes tienen en cuenta el contexto

Basándome en lo que he visto, los usuarios hacen un trabajo genial revisando los reportes. Normalmente leen suficiente de la conversación para entender el contexto y validar o invalidar un reporte correctamente.

Por supuesto, los sitios internacionales son un poco especiales...

#### Los usuarios usan herramientas de traducción para entender el contenido de los sitios internacionales

Aunque las tecnologías de traducción automática no son perfectas, pueden ayudar a entender el sentido de una frase. No he visto una palabra normal que se haya traducido a una palabra malsonante a menudo. Como resultado, suelo pensar (como muchos otros) que si una frase no parece adecuada después de la traducción, probablemente tampoco parece adecuada antes de la traducción (¡de lo contrario nadie usaría los traductores automáticos!)

Si piensas que has sido malinterpretado, no dudes en contactar al equipo de moderadores o CM. ¡Estaremos encantados de ayudarte!

#### Los sitios públicos educados pueden ser lugares divertidos

Cuando alguien me pregunta sobre el nivel de educación que debemos mantener en los sitios, le respondo lo siguiente:

1. En el sitio esperamos que uno se comportase como lo haría si estuviera en una clase de la universidad y el profesor le estuviera preguntando algo o respondiendo al profesor en una clase llena de gente.
2. En el chat esperamos que uno se comportase como si se queda después de clase y hablara de forma informal con el profesor y sus compañeros sobre temas abstractos (aún en la clase universitaria).

He sido parte de muchas conversaciones de ese tipo tanto durante una clase como después de la misma. Hay muchos chistes positivos y anécdotas. Era divertido y como resultado, uno quería hablar con el profesor y sus compañeros de nuevo.

Creo que podemos expresarnos usando palabras que no requieren contexto para entender si son amables o no, palabras que son inclusivas y no ofenden a nadie, palabras que hacen que nos sintamos más cercanos a los demás. Usemos ese lenguaje.

Comment: There is an effort in Teachers' Lounge and Stack Moderators to give visibility to the list of mods who speak different languages, so they are pinged when non-English flags occur, so people who would resolve through a translation do not need to intervene. This case was a good example of this need.

Answer (score 9):

Pensaba quedarme al margen porque ya dije lo que tenía que decir en el chat pero viendo la que se está montando aquí he decidido aportar mi visión en todo el asunto.

Yo soy la persona a la que iba dirigido el mensaje de la discordia, lo primero decir que en ningún momento me sentó mal ni me pareció insultante ni de mal gusto ya que conozco un poco la forma de expresarse de Asier y tenemos cierta confianza de muchos días tratándonos en el chat.

Entiendo a los que la palabra *puto* les parece malsonante, de hecho yo también creo que aunque en ciertos contextos no tiene una connotación negativa es una palabra vulgar que pueda resultar incómoda para muchos pero de ahí a censurarla sin más va un trecho. A mi personalmente no me gusta que en ambientes distendidos e informales como puede ser el chat de SOes no podamos hablar como lo haríamos en cualquier otro entorno entre amigos, tampoco se trata de usar palabrotas a diestro y siniestro pero un exabrupto de vez en cuando no lo veo tan grave.

Como ya han comentado otros usuarios el contexto siempre es importante, no se pueden juzgar las cosas aisladamente. Podríamos hacer una lista de palabras prohibidas y al que las use, *ban* al canto, a mi eso me parece algo horrible, prefiero analizar cada caso y actuar sobre ellos individualmente y no de forma general. Por otra parte el tema de la FIFA que se ha comentado es una comparación absurda ya que las circunstancias y la intención es esa situación son totalmente distintas.

A mi lo que más me molestó en todo este asunto y lo comenté en el chat en su momento es que en lugar de pedir que se editara el comentario o se iniciara un debate sobre el uso del lenguaje en el chat y tratar de aclarar el tema (como hicimos un día con otro asunto sobre memes) se levantó directamente un *flag* sabiendo que podía conllevar una suspensión. Como he expresado en otras ocasiones creo que hablar los temas y discutirlos es la mejor forma de tratar cualquier problema o discrepancia. En esta comunidad, salvo alguna triste excepción, creo que hay voluntad de entendimiento y se puede llegar a consensos discutiendo las cosas.

También quiero pedirle a @AsieR_2 que no se lo tome como algo personal ya que no creo que lo sea, ni por quien levantó el flag, ni por el moderador que lo baneo, ni por la gente que está participando en este hilo; creo que es un tema de sensibilidades distintas sin más.

Answer (score 8):

Imagina que un usuario nuevo, llega al chat por curiosidad, y lee tu comentario ¿Qué imagen recibe como primera impresión? Ahora, imagina que a esa persona, se le ocurre hablar de la misma manera, se desvirtuaría todo.

El chat esta desde hace mucho tiempo, y va a seguir estando, pero para ellos se tiene que mantener un orden, por mas que tengas confianza con las personas.

En cuanto al reporte, si bien es mejor tener una causa del mismo, creo que no hace falta en tu caso. Esta clara la causa y la resolución del mismo.
Yo mismo reportaría un comentario así de haberlo leído a tiempo. En tu caso, no es la primera vez que usas palabras fuera de todo ni lenguaje muy de "confianza".
Si bien el chat es un lugar más relajado para hablar con compañeros de código, no se puede hablar en esos tonos.
Tampoco me parece que tengas que escribir en una pregunta "los 4 gatos de siempre" o escribir "podría suspender ahora mismo a 20 personas si me diese la gana".

Ya llevas un tiempo en el sitio, así que tuviste tiempo de sobra para aprender como comportarte. 
Revisa el **[Código de conducta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/conduct)** si te hace falta.

Puede que mi respuesta tenga un tono un tanto agresivo, pero no es la idea, ni tengo nada personal contra ti. Solo doy mi opinión al respecto.

Comment: Si ahora va a resultar que la expresión los 4 gatos de siempre es ofensiva.

Comment: Y que podría suspender a 20 persoans a base de flags es un hecho, otra cosa es que lo quieras ver de otro modo.

Comment: @AsieR_2 sé que puede resultar frustrante cuando te "castigan" sólo a ti por algo que otros también hacen, es normal sentirse así. En mi caso ante una discusión en meta, trato de seguir como consejo lo que piensa la mayoría, esto para corregir mi comportamiento y evitar caer en algo que "esté mal". Hasta el momento llevas 5 downvotes (pueden ser más pero no los puedo ver), creo que es suficiente para entender el mensaje.

Comment: El problema es que no comparto esa visión. La queja no está en me han castigado solo a mi. Está en me han castigado por X.

Answer (score 6):

*My two cents*, como dicen los anglosajones:

Quizá necesitemos un enlace en el propio chat a las normas de uso, porque realmente toda esta polémica no existiría si hubiésemos leído las reglas:

> ## [What can we chat about?](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#about)
>
> This site is an extension of The Stack Exchange Network, **so
> discussion should more or less revolve around the same topics** you'd
> find at The Stack Exchange Network — but in an interactive, less
> strictly Q&A focused way. **Do have fun, but please keep it
> professional** and always be respectful of your fellow community
> members.

[Y de una pregunta/respuesta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270590/252459):

> ## Toward a philosophy of Chat
>
> On chat, I see a lot of rooms with "regulars" - a small group of folks
> that have been in the room since its conception, and continue to play
> major roles in the dynamics of conversations there. They often have
> personalities that get along well together, and so they agree on
> certain things - including the room's informal "policies". Over time -
> weeks, months, years - the standards of behavior gradually align with
> this group's expectations. They're the major players in the dramas of
> chat, and so they set a standard. New users see that these regulars
> are the main folks here, and so they might change their behaviors
> accordingly. Without outside intervention, you very quickly build up
> what's called "room culture". The phrase "room culture" is generally
> used defensively. When a moderator or other flag-handler deletes a
> chat message, suspends a user, or otherwise acts in a way that the
> regulars don't like, they can be attacked for it. Worse still are
> cases when the moderator isn't a moderator on the site. They'll then
> be called an outsider, someone who just doesn't understand the "room
> culture". I think that at least part of the problem here stems from
> this idea, and I've seen certain recent issues on chat parallel this
> pretty closely. It all comes down to an attitude issue - and I know
> that that sounds harsh, but it is the truth. The attitude that some
> folks are above the overarching chat policies and can make their own
> rules because they're established is one that can cause problems.

No voy a traducir ahora mismo todo esto, pero en resumen:

- El lenguaje en el chat debe ser similar al que usaríamos en el resto del sitio. Se acepta que nos relajemos un poco o que nos salgamos del tema principal (en nuestro caso la programación) un poco, pero todo debería girar sobre este tema.
- En toda sala hay *habituales*, usuarios que están presentes casi todos los días y llevan ahí desde el principio. Eso hace que estos usuarios tiendan a tener la voz cantante e influyan mucho en lo que se dice y en cómo se dice. Con el tiempo esta *cultura de la sala* tiende a desviarse del comportamiento estándar del chat. Son los protagonistas de los *dramas* y cuando un moderador ajeno a la sala borra o marca un mensaje como irrespetuoso, éste puede verse atacado por ello (no entiende de qué se está hablando, esto se ha hecho así siempre... etc). En realidad, las normas de la sala son las mismas en todas las salas y no podemos/debemos salirnos de ellas.

Answer (score 5):

He saltado en el tiempo [hasta el punto inicial de la conversación](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/30872?m=50749979#50749979) que indica Asier para intentar reconstruir la situación, como si del VAR se tratara. Si alguien ve alguna inconsistencia, que por favor me la indique o la edite directamente:

- Asier y otras personas comentan sobre un tema.
- Tras algunas frases, Asier dice:

  > @X díselo a A, puto
- Un usuario hasta el momento ausente en la conversación anuncia que ha reportado el mensaje, aduciendo que si alguien nuevo entra en el chat, qué va a pensar. Añade que no se siente cómodo en un lugar donde la gente se trata así.
- Un moderador de la red ve el reporte y lo da por válido a las 12.33 h. Otro moderador es el que posteriormente suspende manualmente y por 60 minutos, a las 12.38 h. Entre las 12.33 y las 12.38 h no hay baneo, pues [a las 12.37 h Asier dice cosas](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/50750264/history), por ejemplo. Estos 60 minutos probablemente sean resultado de los 30 minutos iniciales por un reporte *ofensivo* sumado a otro ([fuente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271270/209901)), pero no he obtenido respuesta del segundo moderador cuando le he preguntado.

Hasta aquí los hechos.

---

Añado algún elemento creo que también bastante objetivable:

- El chat, igual que el resto de elementos de la red Stack Exchange, se regula por el [Código de conducta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/conduct). Por tanto, es de lógica que se establezca una conversación constructiva y que no haga sentir a la gente mal.
- La palabra *puto* es malsonante siempre. Ahora bien, en España no tiene la [connotación que tiene en muchos países de Hispanoamérica](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=8iyVWuVqSx0Aewr3h0O%7Cp08JURzRjx0AWKEuap6).
- Se ha mencionado también en este hilo que *qué dirá alguien nuevo si entra y ve que alguien llama a otro *puto**.
- Los reportes llegan sin contexto. El moderador ve un número azul, aprieta y ve la línea exacta reportada junto con el posible motivo de reporte. Puede aceptar el reporte o negarlo. No tiene información extra por defecto (debe buscarla).

Creo que todos estos elementos válidos. Sin embargo, en este caso creo que ha faltado bastante **proporcionalidad**, así como **mano izquierda**. Me explico: la persona que reportó como *ofensivo* sabía perfectamente (porque ha sido moderador) que un reporte así conlleva una suspensión larga (30 minutos). En el tiempo que transcurrió entre que se dijo la palabra (12.29 h) y el flag se dio por válido, no habían ni siquiera transcurrido cinco minutos, que son el tiempo que da el sistema para editar un comentario. Creo que habría sido mucho más constructivo indicar que no resultaba cómodo y animar a rectificar, en lugar de lanzar la bomba nuclear para neutralizar esa palabra.

Si se me permite el símil, el chat es como una plaza donde va pasando gente, se sienta, juega un rato, charla, se va, llegan otros.
En este caso, sería como si unos cuantos están hablando, uno suelta algo que no gusta a otro que está a lo lejos, el cual de repente avisa que no solo no le gusta lo que ha dicho, sino que ya ha avisado a la policía (o instancia similar) denunciándolo. ¿No sería desproporcionado? ¿No sería más lógico, habiendo como parece que había, primero comentar y, de persistir, ya avisar a "la policía"?

Volviendo a nuestro chat, resulta bastante paradójico que estemos protegiendo más a un hipotético usuario que pueda aparecer en cualquier momento, antes que al usuario regular que ya está formando parte de él. Seamos equilibrados.

Animo a tratar este tema con la lógica que merece. Que una cosa sea incorrecta no quiere decir que su respuesta pueda ser de cualquier tipo. Una acción mala no debe tratarse con la bomba nuclear.

Comment: Y en la misma conversación con él le digo que puede borrar el comentario si así lo desea. https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50750184#50750184

Comment: Dejemos de lado la justicia por un momento, cualquier llamada de atención es incómoda, pero vamos, una suspension de **una hora** está muy lejos, pero muy lejos de una "bomba nuclear"

Comment: Pienso que despues de varios días se pueden sacar algunas conclusiones, hubo errores de muchos lados. 1) no se debe usar palabras malsonantes en cualquier espacio de SO para evitar este tipo de discusiones, 2) Siempre es mejor informar el motivo de la sanción, 3) Si se cometio un error ya se tuvo un castigo y probablemente ya que se deberia cometer el mismo error, 4) La sanción de una hora es acorde a lo que se hizo comparando con otras sanciones como la suspensión de un dia, un mes o la eliminación del usuario.

Comment: @Rubén asumo que la elección de la palabra es tal vez excesiva, pero mi punto es que se eligió antes la bomba que muchas otras herramientas menos potentes pero probablemente más útiles para terminar con un conflicto de forma más civilizada para todas las partes.

Comment: @eyllanesc sobre 2) eso no es posible por la propia tecnología actual del chat de [se]. Sobre 4) ¿qué baremos utilizas para afirmarlo? Además no es lo mismo sanciones en el chat que al usuario principal.

Answer (score -4):

No pensaba meterme en esta discusión ya que, soy uno de los usuarios que más rompe las normas de conducta que se han de tener en el chat, probablemente más de la mitad de los "puto" en el historial sean míos. Aún así, creo conveniente expresar mi punto de vista, ya que creo (tras haber leído las respuestas por encima) que nadie ha mencionado que el moderador pudo haber actuado mal.

---

En toda la conversación **no han habido faltas de respeto** entre las dos partes y eso es lo que debería de valorarse, el chat es un sitio sano donde se discuten de diversos temas, aunque se usen palabras normales, rara vez se falta el respeto entre usuarios y el `flag` emitido a Asier me parece totalmente injustificado.

No es la primera vez que un moderador de un sitio externo *suspende* a un usuario de StackOverflow en español sin tener en cuenta el contexto de la conversación. El año pasado, cuando apenas estaba empezando a conocer a la gente del chat reporté al **moderador** @lois6b y un moderador de un sitio externo lo suspendió.
 https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/30872?m=44038536#44038536
[image: Captura de chat]

Ni siquiera recuerdo el motivo, recuerdo que estábamos de risas y me entere de esto después, ni siquiera puse algo coherente en el reporte seguro, por que nunca lo he hecho.

Esto claramente **demuestra una completa falta de interés y de seriedad** por parte de **algunos moderadores** hacía comunidades externas a las que pertenecen, y este perfectamente podría haber sido uno de esos casos.

Más ejemplos y más absurdos son las suspensiones al usuario @Pikoh por enviar memes al chat.

---

Respecto a la actitud de G3rv4, no me parece mal (Aunque si me parece una falta total de tolerancia) que haya reportado algo que a él le parece mal o algo con lo que no está de acuerdo, creo que su elección, pese a no haber sido la más correcta en el momento, ya que podía haber hablado con Asier, es completamente aceptable.

---

Sobre los usuarios nuevos, dudo que nadie entre en el chat y piense que andamos diciéndonos barbaridades unos a otros constantemente, casi siempre se habla con respeto y educación, y rara vez se cometen faltas de respeto.

Pensar que un usuario nuevo puede interpretar un "puto" como un motivo para no quedarse en el chat es lo mismo que pensar que un usuario puede entender el chat como un ambiente demasiado formal y artificial como para no entrar en el mismo.

Tanto la falta de "educación y modales", como el exceso de los mismos pueden ser motivos para *"espantar"* a usuarios.

---

Creo que el problema aquí no está en usar la palabra *puto* o no usarla ni tampoco en las acciones tomadas por G3rv4.

Pese a que muchas veces **en muchos contextos** es una palabra vulgar y malsonante, no es una palabra que debería de censurarse sin tener el cuenta el contexto en el que se dice. No creo que censurar sea la forma correcta de actuar.

Pese a las normas de conducta del sitio, creo que, mientras que no se le falte el respeto a ningún usuario, personalmente estoy completamente en contra de que se censure el lenguaje, sea más o menos vulgar.

**Creo que son los moderadores los que deberían de mirar que es lo que suspenden y que es lo que no**, es muy fácil banear a un usuario y quitarte del problema de encima en vez de lidiar con ello.

Mientras esto no se mire y mientras no se hablen las cosas, vamos a tener el mismo problema una y otra vez y vamos a acabar convirtiendo StackOverflow en una comunidad tóxica, super correcta, donde todos vamos a tener que estar tratándonos con pinzas para no ofendernos unos a otros.

Answer (score -6):

Tl;Dr

Stack Exchange tiene https://spanish.stackexchange.com donde se pueden hacer preguntas y respuestas sobre el lenguaje español. Los invito a lleven la discusión de la palabra polémica a ese espacio y dejemos este para centrarnos a los que a SOes atañe. Según entiendo en el contexto de esta pregunta es **aclarar el funcionamiento de las suspensiones temporales en el chat**.

---

Cabe mencionar que bajo ninguna circunstancia, con excepción de si se trata del nombre de vulgar de una herramienta o lenguaje de programación, se deber usar lenguaje soez. Sólo en los sitios sobre lengua puede hacerse en los hilos que tratan sobre una palabra en particular.

- [¿Está permitido en los sitios de SE el lenguaje soez (maldiciones, grocerías, lenguaje vulgar, palabras malsonantes)?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4217/65)
- [Copiar lenguaje soez y palabras obsenas en Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4219/65)

---

Al menos en mi otra respuesta han habido varios comentarios que sobre si una palabra en particular es o no es vulgar. El primero fue este

> En cuanto al uso de *la palabra en cuestión*, en España no tiene para nada la connotación que tiene en ciertas zonas de Hispanoamérica. Por ello, que *el OP* de España la utilice con otra persona de este mismo país excluye esa connotación. Con un idioma tan diverso y extendido, tener en cuenta todas las connotaciones sería una locura. ¿No podemos decir concha, por ejemplo?

He estado en España sólo en una ocasión. Conozco españoles que han venido a México de visita y a residir permanentemente y he coincidido con ellos en eventos en Estados Unidos, y Argentina. Hemos hablado sobre el uso del lenguaje incluyendo cuales palabras son vulgares en diferentes países y contextos, pero la palabra en cuestión no había tomado tanta atención salvo en dos situaciones, este hilo y el comentar la situación de las sanciones a México por parte de la FIFA.

Además del comentario citado arriba el OP ha editado su pregunta para decir

> **ACLARACIÓN**: En ESPAÑA, o hasta dónde yo sé en mi entorno, *la palabra en cuestión* no es un insulto y nadie en su sano juicio lo utilizaría para insultar, básicamente porque se reirían de ti. (A diferencia de la versión terminada en a) Pero oye, ahora por lo visto esto es SOLatam y las normas las ponéis vosotros así que ok.

Aunque ya lo mencioné en un comentario, dejo aquí lo publicado por un diario español en el 2017

> **La FIFA se lanza contra el grito de *la palabra en cuestión* y todos los actos discriminatorios en la Copa Confederaciones**
>
> El máximo organismo del fútbol ha autorizado a los árbitros centrales para suspender los juegos si se presenta algún comportamiento homofóbico o racista del público

En la nota el diario español no critica a la FIFA ni dice que sean los latinoamericanos quienes rijan el lenguaje español en los eventos de la FIFA fuera del suelo mexicano. Tampoco cuestiona que la FIFA considere la palabra en cuestión como homofóbica

Otra nota del mismo diario, también del 2017 dice

> **La FIFA expulsó de la Copa Confederaciones a dos aficionados que gritaron *la palabra en cuestión***
>   Agentes antidiscriminación retiraron del estadio Fisht de Sochi a un par de mexicanos que gritaron el polémico cántico al portero de Nueva Zelanda

Lo anterior es relevante como ejemplo de una situación del uso del lenguaje en un contexto international, que si bien empezó en el Mundial de Brasil de 2014 continuó en Rusia.

Dejando de lado lo anterior, la temática de Meta es no es el uso general del lenguaje pero si lo es cuando procede o no las suspensiones temporales y cómo protestarlas, lamentablemente en esta pregunta se le está dando demasiada atención a lo primero.

Comment: No entiendo esta respuesta.

Comment: De verdad, Rubén, ayúdame a entender qué pretendes inducir con esta respuesta porque si es lo que parece, resulta muy rebuscado. ¿Qué tiene que ver lo que diga la FIFA, oséase un caso concreto de un contexto totalmente diferente, con una palabra dicha en un chat?

Comment: @fedorqui he editado la respuesta.

Comment: Pues me sigue pareciendo un sinsentido. La clave de la discusión es la interpretación de la palabra

Comment: @fedorqui Pues ese justamente es el punto de esta respuesta (al menos de revisión actual), si la discusión se va a centrar en la interpretación de la palabra me parece que el mejor lugar para ello es  [spanish.se].

Comment: La queja de Asier es que una palabra que para él es inocua en el contexto en el que la dijo, para otra persona no lo fue y por eso la reportó. Creo que quitar ese elemento de la discusión hace que directamente no haya discusión, de ahí que considere un sinsentido plantearlo.

Comment: Si el propósito del hilo es publicar una queja acerca de que hay personas con privilegios de moderador que interpretan de forma diferente a una comunidad de habla a la que no pertenecen , pues ya se quejó, punto. La pregunta debe ser cerrada como fuera de tema, pues Meta no es para quejas a secas. Si a la queja le suma la queja de cómo funciona el sistema de moderación del chat, pues ya se quejó, punto. Igualmente la pregunta debe ser cerrada por lo dicho. Cosa diferente es que el OP quiera entender cómo funciona el sistema, señale algo que no funciona...

Comment: ... y esté abierto a  conocer la opinión de otros. Si a eso le suma una propuesta, fantástico más no indispensable.

Comment: No amigo mío, para quejarme y ya está no vengo aquí, quiero que algo así no vuelva a ocurrir, pero visto que en la edición me habéis censurado *gentuzo*, (variación ¿humorística? que la RAE ni contempla) que eso ya sí que es de traca, pues ya no sé qué pensar.

Comment: @AsieR_2 Como lo mencioné el hilo parece centrado en una palabra en particular, no en otra cosa. Si tus intenciones son otras considera replantearlas, quizás en una nueva pregunta donde hagas énfasis en lo que no deseas que pase pues en este hilo la conversación se ha centrado en la interpretación de una palabra que no tiene que ver con la temática del sitio.

Comment: No creo que deba cerrarse la pregunta. En Meta hay multitud de preguntas con quejas sobre situaciones. Y aquí es legítimo preguntar y, como he dicho innumerables veces, creo que el análisis del uso de la palabra en el chat es la clave. Claro que Spanish.SE es para hablar de palabras, pero en un sentido más académico; considero un error pretender que no se pueda debatir al respecto en MetaSOes.