# ¿Está permitido en los sitios de SE el lenguaje soez (maldiciones, groserías, vulgaridades, palabras malsonantes)?

Tags: soporte, faq, convenciones-sociales, lenguaje-soez

> Traducción de [Are expletives (cursing, swear words or vulgar language) allowed on SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22232/289691)

¿Puedo usar [lenguaje soez](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenguaje_soez), lenguaje fuerte, cargado, pesado en los sitios de Stack Exchange como [Q*bert](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q*bert)?

[image]

> Para más información, véase [¿Cuál es la conducta esperada de los usuarios?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) en el [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help)

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

Comment: He agregado de vuelta el backlink al índice del FAQ porque de acuerdo a https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/65 que es una traducción en proceso de https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/289691 este se debe incluir en las preguntas con [tag:faq-proposed] de acuerdo a

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Traducción de [la respuesta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22233/289691) a [Are expletives (cursing, swear words or vulgar language) allowed on SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22232/289691)

## NO.

El lenguaje soez no es una conducta aceptable en ningún sitio de Stack Exchange, incluyendo Meta. Hay algunas pocas excepciones (como cuando se está hablando de la palabra misma en un sitio sobre lenguaje), pero en general no debes usar lenguaje soez en ninguna parte, bajo ninguna circunstancia. Si no puedes comunicar efectivamente lo que necesitas decir sin recurrir a las palabras malsonantes, entonces guárdalo para ti mismo.

Si usas lenguaje soez, recibirás una advertencia. Cualquier lenguaje que se vuelve una fuente de disrupción está sujeta a ser removida a través de la edición. Incluso si usas lo que tu consideras la más suave de las palabras malsonantes por estilo y alguien las remueve, déjalas fuera.

Si continúas usando lenguaje soez, serás puesto en una [suspensión temporal](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) (artículo del blog de Stack Overflow en inglés).

Comment: Definitivamente NO debe ser aceptable.