# Copiar lenguaje soez y palabras obscenas en Meta

Tags: discusión, meta, lenguaje-soez

> Traducción de [Copying profanities and obscene words on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172734/289691)

Establezcamos esto de una vez por todas. Cuando se discuten posts o comentarios (en cualquier sitio Meta), ¿existe un problema al copiar lenguaje soez y palabras obscenas de la publicación o comentario que es relevante para la discusión?

Existen dos extremos:

1. Sin lenguaje soez: debe ser removido/censurado, para prevenir que los cortafuegos corporativos filtren los sitios de Stack Exchange basados en esas palabras vulgares.
2. El lenguaje soez no es un problema: no es política de Stack Exchange el remover/censurar este lenguaje. Déjalo en la publicación y respeta la voluntad e intención del autor.

Yo me inclino por la opción 1 sólo para estar del lado seguro, aunque personalmente no me agrada.

---

Esta pregunta es resultado directo de la edición y reversión hecha [en la respuesta a *Why was this edit approved?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/172684/revisions) la cual, debido a eso, ha sido bloqueada.

> NOTA DEL TRADUCTOR: La pregunta original fue publicada en OS Meta y migrada a Meta SE, aparentemente el proceso de migración no incluye las ediciones, por lo que no está disponible. Se conserva porque la respuesta, que también es una traducción, hace referencia al enlace incluido.

Traducción de [Copying profanities and obscene words on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172734/289691)

Comment: Esta pregunta se incluye porque el wiki de la etiqueta "profanity" de Meta SE incluye el enlace a la pregunta original y he propuesto un wiki de etiqueta similar para [tag:lenguaje-soez] la cual también se incluyó en la traducción del FAQ sobre si es válido usar lenguaje soez: [¿Está permitido en los sitios de SE el lenguaje soez (maldiciones, groserías, lenguaje vulgar, palabras malsonantes)?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4217/65)

Comment: Creo que la propuesta de incorporar info de Meta.SE a nuestro Meta.SOes en este caso ha sido fallida: la pregunta elegida es un despropósito de enlaces rotos y la traducción es eso + una serie de explicaciones sobre la pregunta inicial. Un lío. Sería mejor empezar desde cero y crear nosotros el contenido.

Comment: Si una empresa con programadores bloquea stackoverflow con el cortafuegos, manda al departamento de desarrollo a pique.

Answer (score 0):

> Traducción de [la respuesta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172736/289691) a [Copying profanities and obscene words on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172734/289691)

A menos que *lo necesites*, no lo uses. Si lo necesitas, no te preocupes.

El ejemplo que disparó esto no lo necesita - la vulgaridad en cuestión está a simple vista *en la revisión que el AP enlazó!*.

Un ejemplo de "necesidad" podría ser discutir un filtro de lenguaje soez potencial, o quizás el nombre vulgar de una [herramienta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110726/289691)  o [lenguaje de programación](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/24079/289691). Incluso entonces, *intenta* mantenerlo profesional; las vulgaridades por la vulgaridad por si misma es para lo que los comentarios de YouTube están.

He limpiado la respuesta que enlazaste y la he desbloqueado.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien esta publicación, en la respuesta hay alguna frase general que puede servir para otros casos pero tiene demasiado ruido. En dos ocasiones se habla de un *post* que ya no existe y hace una apreciación personal sobre Youtube que creo que sobra. Aunque la respuesta sea de un trabajador de SE la veo bien para enlazarla en la discusión que inició todo esto o en otra publicación que podamos crear para tratar este tema pero así traducida sin más la veo confusa y vaga.

Comment: @blonfu si la falta de claridad es meramente sobre el contenido y no sobre su traducción, considera publicar tu comentario en la publicación original así el autor del mismo podrá hacer la aclaraciones que resulten pertinentes. Lamentablemente ya no estan a la vista los comentarios que intercambiamos fedorqui y yo sobre el enlace en los llegamos a la conclusión que la pregunta original fue migrada y en la migración se perdió la publicación referido por ello ni los usuarios con rep >10k pueden verla.

Comment: @blonfu He agregando nuevamente a la pregunta el párrafo al que hace referencia la respuesta y modificado la nota del traductor que había colocado originalmente.

Comment: No tengo nada en contra de tu traducción, era por el contenido de la respuesta original que sin la publicación a la que hacía referencia apenas queda una frase que tenga sentido para nosotros. No vi vuestros comentarios hablando del tema