# Lenguaje vulgar en el chat de SOes

Tags: discusión, soporte, moderación, código-de-conducta, suspensiones-chat

Hoy vengo, de nuevo, a reclamar sobre una suspensión reciente que tuve en el chat.

Estábamos hablando como siempre y alguien menciono algo como 
*"si lo preguntas, no eres gaymer"*, a lo que respondí algo como que no soportaba el término "gamer" y parodié a mí manera a la gente que se hace llamar como tal con lo siguiente:

[image: Captura del flag.]

De nuevo, desde mi punto de vista no he faltado el respeto a absolutamente nadie y he respetado el código de conducta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/conduct

Dónde habla de que el lenguaje vulgar no ha de ser usado en lo referente al acoso, cuando yo no he acosado a nadie.

[image: Captura extraída del código de conducta de SOes]

Claramente y como se ve en la captura, se lee: **Esto incluye**.

---

Esto me lleva a pensar dos cosas.

**La primera:** La gente que reporta los comentarios no es lo suficientemente adulta o es extremadamente sensible e intolerante. En todo caso, siento que es a mí a quien se me acosa al limitarme la libertad de expresión.

**La segunda:** El moderador que ejerce la suspensión temporal no conoce del todo el código de conducta.

**La tercera:** Malinterpreto lo que se dice en el código de conducta sobre el uso del lenguaje vulgar, en cuyo caso creo que haría falta una revisión o una modificación del mismo, por que tal y como está escrito, no estoy saltándome las normas.

Creo que esto habría que mirarlo desde un punto neutral; como adultos, y no como gente extremadamente sensible. En este caso era puro humor, parodia, en la que no se pretendía faltar al respeto a nadie, y dudo que alguien pudiera sentirse ofendido.

---

Espero que algún moderador participe en la discusión para dar su punto de vista. Personalmente este tipo de actitudes no me parecen normales.

Comment: @KacosPro Bandas negras en un videojuego en 2019, FLAG.

Comment: @AsieR_2   

Comment: Si no lo has hecho aún por for lee [¿Está permitido en los sitios de SE el lenguaje soez (maldiciones, groserías, vulgaridades, palabras malsonantes)?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4217/65)

Comment: En esta ocasión no estoy de acuerdo con la suspensión. Revisé la conversación del chat y a pesar de que se menciona la palabra **odio**, claramente no está incitando al odio, simplemente expresa que eso no le gusta. En todo caso, se debió haber suspendido a @lois6b ya que la palabra **gaymer** hace referencia a la homosexualidad, pero de igual manera si tuviera el poder de decisión haría consenso para ver si realmente requiere la suspensión y yo votaría por el no.

Comment: Creo que tenemos que elevar esto mucho mas arriba. Aca ni gilipollas ni lo otro son un insulto, porque esas palabras ni siquiera existen aca...

Comment: @Rubén No considero que en ningún momento haya usado lenguaje soez, de todas formas, citando un mensaje del chat: El lenguaje vulgar lo empleamos en las relaciones ordinarias, en la conversación habitual, por lo que se habla también de lenguaje coloquial, familiar o popular. El lenguaje obsceno es lenguaje vulgar, pero no todo lenguaje vulgar es obsceno. Y yo personalmente no creo que haya empleado lenguaje obsceno en el chat. Entendiendo que el lenguaje obsceno es un lenguaje considerado ofensivo.

Comment: @gbianchi completamente de acuerdo, tenemos que zanjar este tema. Aunque creo que el problema es el abuso de la banderita y no el lenguaje que se usa en el chat. A nada que algo se puede malinterpretar directamente se flagea sea o no ofensivo.

Comment: No te acusaba de usar lenguaje soez, de hecho, me parece lo que mencionas en tu comentario deberías de incluirlo en tu "reclamo".

Comment: @Rubén no he dicho que me acuses, simplemente lo aclaro.

Comment: Lamentablemente las dos palabras que me parece que podrían haber sido motivo de reporte aparecen en el dle como malsonantes.

Comment: @Rubén Creo que aislar las palabras para evaluarlas una a una es lo peor que se puede hacer. Todo sacado de contexto puede ser malsonante dependiendo de quien lo mire. Pero en fin. Sigue sin ser un comentario malsonante en conjunto, creo yo.

Comment: Quizás, pero sólo Dios sabe lo que hay en la cabeza de los moderadores (entiéndase los que pueden hacer reportes y evaluarlos) y de que herramientas se valen si es que lo hacen cuando hay duda.

Comment: @PaulVargas Qué quieres decir?

Comment: @Phi no me habia llegado el ping por no haber puesto ningun comentario ni edicion. Hacer referencia a la homosexualidad no es algo negativo y no fue esa mi intención. Yo jugaba con ese termino por el juego de palabras en la pronunciación de *gamer* ( gamer == gueimer == gaymer ). Además, yo no lo uso peyorativamente e incluso dije que aritz **no** lo es. Un saludo

Comment: @AsieR_2 Me refería a que se preocupan demasiado por algo tan efímero.

Comment: @PaulVargas Pues había sonado fatal :/

Answer (score 12):

Muchas gracias a [@Pikoh](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15301/pikoh) por la traducción.

---

Eché un vistazo al historial de flags de la [sala de stack overflow en español](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) y el mensaje que estaba marcado. Permitídme compartir algunas reflexiones sobre el tema.

#### El sistema te suspendió porque varios usuarios han votado, no por la voluntad de un usuario

Parece que han participado 14 personas, una que marcó y trece que revisaron el flag:

- Un usuario invalidó el flag.
- Seis usuarios no estaban seguros del flag.
- Los otros seis usuarios marcaron el flag como válido.

Entonces, el ratio de resultados es 1:6. Fue una decisión comunitaria sobre el mensaje, no personal de alguien. Además, fue una decisión de los usuarios "normales": los usuarios que validaron el flag, excepto uno, son usuarios con reputación de >10k .

#### ¿Qué haría yo personalmente si viera el mensaje?

Lamento mucho decir eso pero también validaría el flag. Hablo dos idiomas: ruso e ingles. Traduje el mensaje a ambos usando unos pocos traductores en línea. Sea cual sea el resultado, me pareció ofensivo.

#### Por favor usa el lenguaje neutral

[El idioma español es muy popular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_number_of_native_speakers), se habla en muchos paises. Puedo asumir que podría suceder que la misma palabra se interprete de manera diferente en diferentes regiones. Como resultado, personalmente solo veo una forma de usar el sistema de chat para evitar una suspensión injusta: no utilices palabras que parezcan ofensivas o que puedan interpretarse como ofensivas en diferentes culturas.

Creo que es bastante factible: no puedo recordar fácilmente palabras que sean aceptables en ruso pero que serían vulgares en inglés. Aunque [hay algunas](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7140/6), pero la cuestión es que esas palabras son raras, en el límite, y generalmente nadie las usa en una discusión educada. Esas palabras son en su mayoría jerga. Como resultado, pedimos constantemente a los usuarios que eviten usarlas en nuestros sitios.

#### El chat es un lugar público por defecto

Por favor, [permíteme repetirlo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4227/10): cuando se habla en una sala de chat de Stack Exchange, se está hablando en público. A pesar de que algún tipo de discurso podría estar bien para ti y para el que está hablando, hay muchos otros que lo ven y puede que no les guste lo que dijiste. Si esto es así, pueden marcar un mensaje, y el flag será revisado por otros usuarios. Así es como funciona Stack Exchange.

Comment: ¿Que 6 personas omiten el flag no te parece remarcable? / That 6 people omit the flag does not seem remarkable?

Comment: @AsieR_2 omitir no es lo mismo que no dar por bueno. Puede haber múltiples razones, de la misma manera que en las colas de revisión uno puede seleccionar la opción "omitir".

Comment: @fedorqui En el momento en el que omites estás dando un no implícito o así lo veo yo. En las revisiones si omito es porque no me parece apta pero no sé cómo actuar.

Comment: @AsieR_2 habría que ver qué quiere decir con _omitir_ exactamente en los reportes: si es apretar "omitir" como en las revisiones o si es más bien verlo y no hacer nada.

Comment: Nicolas: what does it mean that users were unsure? That they saw the flag and did not act on it?

Comment: @fedorqui entiendo que se refiere a pulsar _not sure_ en el flag. Si no haces nada, no entrarías en las estadísticas (el flag nos llega a todos los usuarios >10k)

Comment: @fedorqui Pos eso, yo lo veo como un no implícito xD

Comment: @AsieR_2 los *flag* de los chats llegan a todos los usuarios a partir de cierta reputación, la mayoría seguramente no hablen castellano y no se mojen porque no pueden juzgar correctamente el contexto. Es como cuando me llegan a mi *flags* de chat rusos, por ejemplo.

Comment: @blonfu Pues estaría bien saber el sitio 'padre' de los 13 que han votado.

Comment: @AsieR_2 (Sorry, for using English). When somebody flags a message, reviewers have three options: (1) validate the flag, if they sure that the message is offensive; (2) invalidate the flag, if they sure that the message is okay; (3) press "not sure" if they are not sure about the content of the message.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Can we know the main site of the 13 reviewers?

Comment: @AsieR_2 They are all over the network.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Yeah, but I want to know if the 'not sure' people is really 'foreigner' when the validators are not.

Comment: @AsieR_2 I took a look at data. It seems among those six who were not sure, there is only one person who speaks Spanish.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky And the other 7?

Comment: @AsieR_2 The one, who invalidated the flag is a Spanish speaking person (it is worth mention here that this person has a few chat suspensions for posting inappropriate content). One of the six who validated the flag is 100% speaks Spanish, two users may speak Spanish,  three others probably do not speak Spanish.

Answer (score 4):

Me gustaría aportar una visión un poco más general del estado de los **chat** en la red. Nada de lo que aquí se discute hace referencia al **sitio 'padre'** donde es obvio no se permite nada de esto y el lenguaje a de ser formal si es posible.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esa es la tabla de palabras malsonantes más comunes (me atrevería a decir) en nuestro chat y otros 5 chat de programación de habla inglesa. *Casi* tenemos el **ratio más bajo** de palabras malsonantes de los 6. Pese a todo esto, se está *forzando* la idea de prohibir de manera **absoluta** toda palabra malsonante por evitar interpretar su intencionalidad en base al contexto. 
Esto genera dos problemas:

- La evaluación de las palabras sin contexto: las palabras sin contexto no tienen valor y es algo que no se puede negar. Destacar que en el propio Code of Conduct el contexto se tiene en cuenta en los ejemplos.
- La arbitrariedad en la selección de palabras no válidas genera casos como el de 'imbécil', que es un adjetivo y no malsonante; por ello, podría usarse en el ejemplo del OP y no podría ser censurable.

**En resumen:**
Me opongo por completo a la *batalla* que están llevando acabo algunos por hacer del Chat de SOes una iglesia. Considero que el [código de conducta](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct), [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126017/are-expletives-allowed-in-se-chat) en inglés y el [FAQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq) del chat nos avalan para hablar como ya se habla y más respecto a las restricciones que se proponen.

Añadido a petición del autor del mensaje:

Mensaje TOP 1 del chat: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50478637#50478637

Mensaje TOP ¿2? del chat: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42891534#42891534

Comment: La palabra *imbécil* si bien es un adjetivo, es *usado también como insulto*, por lo tanto creo que raya (está en el límite) en lo que se dice sobre el respeto en el chat de SOes. Es obvio que si llamo a alguien *imbécil* lo estoy insultando, el nivel de dicho insulto no hace que deje de serlo. Si en cambio hago alusiones hacia lo que alguien dice o habla en el chat (por ejemplo: *hablas imbecilidades*, o *lo que dices suena imbécil*), es también una forma de insulto, matizado por el hecho de ser un insulto de forma indirecta. Creo que lo que priva aquí es más el respeto ante todo.

Comment: @MauricioContreras ese es el tema, nos estamos centrando en las palabras cuando el contexto lo es todo, se puede hacer más daño sin usar palabras malsonantes ni insultos de ningún tipo y se pueden usar palabras "feas" sin hacer daño a nadie.

Comment: Por supuesto que el contexto lo es todo, y aunque me opongo a la censura, sea cual sea la causa, también entiendo de *propiedad*. En un ambiente de compadrazgo o de mucha confianza pudiese ser tolerable cierto tipo de palabras. Pero el contexto del chat de SOes va más allá del compadrazgo. Y es allí donde debemos detenernos a pensar un poco antes de soltar tanta verborrea que puede hacer sentir incómodo a alguien que no es parte de dicho compadrazgo. Expresiones más o expresiones menos, somos nosotros mismos los responsables del chat. Y claro que se debe tomar acción y discutir este asunto.

Comment: @MauricioContreras ¿Qué quieres decir con tanta verborrea? Yo creo que hablamos de forma correcta y respetuosa en el chat **siempre**.

Comment: Con *verborrea* sólo me refiero a todo lo que se habla en el chat, que es bastante variado. Si agrego expresiones vulgares a todo lo que digo, me vale un bledo el contexto. Hace tiempo comenté diciendo que si hablo lisuras soy un *mal hablado*. Un usuario sugirió que evitemos usar lenguaje soez y problema arreglado. Si acostumbro a tirarme pedos en mi casa porque estoy en confianza, no puedo trasladar dicha costumbre a un espacio público, hay narices sensibles. Lo mismo sucede en el chat.

Comment: @MauricioContreras no te llevaba la contraria, solo incidía en el hecho de que la intención importa más que las palabras en sí, que no nos quedemos en la anécdota de si las palabras son más o menos malsonante sino en el momento y la forma en que se dicen. Tampoco quiero estar discutiendo sobre esto *ad eternum*. Por mi parte me lo tomo con humor y busco maneras creativas de sortear el asunto.

Comment: @MauricioContreras El lenguaje 'soez' es de uso informal y común, tirarse pedos, no.

Comment: Súmenle las cosas regionales que tenemos en muchos lugares que usan SOes. Pregúntennos a los colombianos, de cuántas formas diferentes usamos una palabra común (e.g. gonorrea, mondá) de formas diversas, desde la descripción de una cosa cualquiera hasta el insulto sin ambages. Esa batalla de no permitir nada sin importar el contexto está más perdida que la del DRM

Comment: @Alfabravo Quería haber buscado también, por comparar y no meter solo palabras más usadas de España. Pero la verdad es que desconozco qué palabras usáis más :S

Comment: @AsieR_2 pues mira que muchos nos tiramos pedos y es parte del ser humanos

Comment: @Alfabravo me refiero a que no hay contexto (salvo estar solo) en el que la gente no evite que, al menos, suenen

Comment: @AsieR_2 que lo intente e igual, a veces se le pasa porque así somos. Y con el hablar es igual pues es algo que hacemos de forma natural y usamos las fórmulas y construcciones cotidianas, especialmente porque tratamos de hacer entender un problema que tenemos. No estamos en un entorno que fomente el sentirnos cohibidos

Comment: @Alfabravo Dios te escuche xD

Comment: Se te ha olvidado poner cual es el comentario mas votado del chat

Comment: @NicolasOñate Ya sales... estarás contento, no?

Comment: @AsieR_2 Mas que por salir, es porque el mas votado es lenguaje vulgar y si no recuerdo mal, el segundo mas votado es el mensaje de el inicio del sitio como oficial con 16 votos

Comment: @NicolasOñate Por eso lo he puesto entre ?¿, porque no estoy seguro de que sea el segundo.

Answer (score -10):

Viéndolo de manera "adulta" no lo encuentro ofensivo, mas bien sin gracia.

El insulto gratuito y/o adjetivos calificativos degradantes como punch line de una humorada son algo muy adolescente ( la excepción se da cuando es inesperado y funciona mejor por repetición ).

Te propongo un remix para la próxima:

---

+ñiñiñiii soy gamer, molo mas que tú

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Y así fue como me suspendieron

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo siento, pero tu publicación no me parece para nada "adulta".

Comment: @EMCode usted entendió todo, tenga su like buen hombre!

Comment: jajaja XD ,,, dislike