# No flagees, mutea

Tags: discusión, chat

Llevamos varias semanas con problemas en el chat con el uso del lenguaje, la limitación del mismo y la falta de entendimiento entre los usuarios.

Hice un post en meta sobre el [uso del lenguaje vulgar](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4242/83), defendiendo que el lenguaje vulgar *per se* no era algo malo: según el código de conducta actual, el lenguaje vulgar no debe de ser usado en cuanto se refiere al acoso hacía otros usuarios. O esta es la interpretación que le doy.

Los votos sobre esa pregunta están muy divididos, tiene 11 votos positivos y 15 negativos.

> No creo que la solución sea limitar el lenguaje o el vocabulario.

No estoy defendiendo el uso del lenguaje vulgar ni la utilización del mismo, pero cuando hay cierta confianza con ciertos usuarios, entiendo que no debería de prohibirse hablar con estos de forma más distendida, más relajada, tal vez un poco menos *correcta*.

El chat es casi siempre un lugar amigable, donde no hay problemas, pero cuando los hay las discusiones sobre el tema se vuelven muy intensas.

> Si no te gusta como habla un usuario, en general, mutéalo.

Entiendo que ni todos somos iguales, ni todos tenemos la misma sensibilidad, ni todos tenemos las mismas costumbres ni las mismas maneras de hablar. Por todo esto quiero recalcar que Stack Exchange tiene una herramienta para **silenciar** a un usuario, para ignorarlo y no ver ninguno de sus mensajes si así no lo quieres.

Creo que la actuación correcta es silenciar al usuario con el que no te llevas bien, pues él no tiene la culpa de que te hayas podido sentir ofendido.

> Diferenciemos lo que es una falta de respeto y lo que no lo es.

Considero que no pocas veces se han reportado mensajes que no deberían haber sido reportados, esto crea más problemas que soluciones. Los reportes, bajo desde mi punto de vista han de ser usados para reportar faltas de respeto directas hacía usuarios o colectivos, no para reportar una palabra vulgar o malsonante que no te ha gustado.

Por eso mismo, quiero invitar a los usuarios que se puedan sentir ofendidos a hacer uso de la herramienta de muteo, pudiendo mutear temporalmente a cierto usuario temporal o permanentemente.

> ¿Qué dice el [Código de conducta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/conduct) actual?

El primer punto:

- **No al acoso.**

  Esto incluye, entre otros: acoso, intimidación, lenguaje vulgar, amenazas directas o indirectas, comentarios sexualmente sugestivos, patrones de contacto social inapropiado e interrupciones sostenidas de la discusión.

Sobre este punto entiendo que el uso del lenguaje vulgar hace referencia al uso del mismo sobre el acoso, excluyendo expresiones como `"¡Que p*ta suerte!"`, por poner un ejemplo o un ejemplo real `"El BFV va como el culo"`, ambas expresiones están **muy alejadas** de poder considerarse faltas de respeto. La segunda se dijo y se castigó con media hora de baneo por hacer un comentario sobre el rendimiento un videojuego.

Segundo punto:

- **No a la intolerancia.**

  No toleramos ninguna frase que pueda ofender o apartar a las personas por motivos de raza, sexo, orientación sexual o religión, y estos son solo algunos ejemplos. En caso de duda, simplemente no lo hagas.

Aquí claramente hace referencia a la intolerancia, entiendo que ciertos usuarios no toleren el lenguaje vulgar, por eso mismo escribo este post, la libre utilización del lenguaje debería ser algo que tendría que tolerarse, siempre y cuando no falte al respeto de ningún usuario.

> Tratemos de entendernos

Hablemos las cosas antes de actuar, si algo te ha ofendido puedes hablarlo, somos adultos, podemos disculparnos, podemos pedirle a un usuario que no haga ciertos comentarios siempre que sean cosas con sentido. "Por favor, no hagas chistes sobre X enfermedad", "Por favor, no hables sobre ese tema", pero me gustaría que tratemos de no limitar el lenguaje como se parece que se está intentando hacer, por que causa más problemas que soluciones y estamos sufriendo consecuencias por esto desde hace varias semanas.

Comment: Que gran ironía, se podrian haber ahorrado tantas cosas ayer si hubieran aplicado esto *(Si no te gusta como habla un usuario, en general, mutealo. )* algunos users..

Comment: @Marc te lo he dicho por el chat, pero lo repito por aquí, siento mi actitud en el día de ayer. No quería provocar todo lo que provoqué y tenía que haberte dicho directamente que me molestaba que eso se quedase ahí.

Comment: Sería bueno que incluyeras al menos un enlace a la herramienta para mutear.

Comment: @Rubén la herramienta para mutear usuarios está implicita en el chat, solo tienes que pinchar sobre la foto del usuario en cuestión y te saldrá botón para mutearlo.

Comment: Supongo que te refieres a "ignore this user (everywhere)" que se muestra en la tarjeta de usuario

Comment: No se si responder o sólo dejar este comentario. Estuve presente en el momento en que entró un *outsider* (como se me ocurrió llamarle), y eliminó la conversación (que tenía palabras vulgares, no lo niego) y puso un ban a los implicados. Decidí salir del chat temporalmente, ya que ese tipo de actitudes (las del *outsider*) por parte de alguien que no habla nuestra lengua de forma nativa, me parecen por demás demasiado injustas. Se ha hablado muchas veces de moderar el lenguaje en el chat, mi llamado es a no exponerse de tal forma, creo que somos profesionales todos, o nos formamos para serlo.

Answer (score 3):

El tema por si mismo es complejo.

¿Por qué?

- Bueno existe un código de conducta que muchos usuarios y usuarias seguirán de forma cabal, eso incluye que lo extrapolen a situaciones donde notan palabras vulgares.
- Por otro lado van a existir los usuarios que de acuerdo con su región geográfica no identifiquen las palabras que otros si conocen como vulgares o que sin importar lo mencionado al inicio no le den importancia alguna

¿Entonces, somos libres o no de expresarnos?

Claro, pero teniendo en cuenta el *posible impacto* que lo que escribamos tenga en los demás, por ejemplo en el caso del chat que por si mismo se pudiera considerar una zona *un tanto neutral* aún así sigue teniendo reglas.

¿Entonces por qué tanto lío con el uso de determinado lenguaje?

Bueno consideremos que nos encontramos en una plataforma cuya finalidad es crear un basto compendio de preguntas y respuestas de calidad en cuanto a programación, dado eso no considero prudente o necesario el uso de determinadas palabras; se comprende perfecto que *somos adultos* pero eso no quita el hecho de que la plataforma es un lugar público donde pueden estar de forma concurrente múltiples usuarios; dado eso es la imagen que *proyectamos y me incluyo* sobre todo para los nuevos.

¿Pero con quien hablo es alguien de mi entera confianza?

Eso lo comprendo, yo mismo suelo recurrir en muchas ocasiones ante reportes a @gbianchi por que considero muy atinadas y maduras sus formas de actuar, pero si creo que estaría fuera de todo lugar comenzar una plática con el rebasando la línea del respeto, es decir refiriéndome a el o usando palabras fuera de lugar para hacerle saber algo.

Digo que es un tema complejo y parto de mi, por la siguiente razón.

Algunas ocasiones yo mismo trato de ayudar en la moderación del sitio y aunque pienso que escribo con el mayor respeto posible, existen usuarios que se la han tomado a mal y piensan que los puedo estar regañando o algo parecido; derivado de eso ya en algún momento me llamaron la atención los mods y aunque yo pudiera decir que no hice algo malo, pienso después: ¿en qué tono lo pudo haber recidido la otra persona, qué entendió realmente de mi mensaje, asumió algo malo?, lejos de enojarme analizo lo que pudo haber pasado para no caer en la misma situación.

Mi recomendación (tratemos de dejar el uso de determinadas palabras que en general sabemos pueden hacer que mas de uno levante la ceja), por fuera de la comunidad; podemos tener pláticas super interesantes *(como la vez que le hice preguntas a @gbianchi)* sobre VueJS *(a como sabe ese hombre de dicho framework, de grande quiero ser como el)* y evitarnos estas situaciones.

¿Por qué recomiendo esto?

Bueno por que en una lista de usuarios de mas de *100,000* va a ser muy difícil alcanzar el acuerdo, siempre habrá a quien algunas cosas no les agraden *lo cual es totalmente respetable*.

Y como dije partiendo de mi, sería mejor analizar tal vez un poco mas lo que puede generar tanto lo que decimos como lo que hacemos.

Ojo, esta es solo una opinión de un usuario X que anda por estos rumbos.

Comment: Precisamente esta recomendación: "tratemos de dejar el uso de determinadas palabras que en general sabemos pueden hacer que mas de uno levante la ceja", es la que una y otra vez tratamos de sugerir. Por cierto excelente trabajo de moderación en el sitio, muchas gracias.

Comment: gracias @Jorgesys hablo por mi, aceptar la observación y tratar de hacer una mejora en la participación puede que nos cueste pero a la larga beneficia mucho mas. Saludos

Comment: Mi llamado también es a eso, en mi tierra se dice: *bájale 2*, para referirse a que hay que ser más prudentes o menos efusivos en alguna situación particular. Sin embargo, en esta oportunidad en concreto se *pasaron de maraca*, como también se dice en mi tierra. La conversación más insulsa, (con palabrotas incluidas, eso no lo niego) manejada de muy mala forma. Habría que ser muy corto (menos de un dedo de frente) para no darse cuenta que simplemente se la *tienen montada* a algunos, que por cierto uno de ellos decidió eliminar su cuenta. Ojalá esto pare aquí, y sepamos mejorar y **aceptar**.

Comment: @MauricioContreras abusaron de los flags, y es le llega a todos los que estan en la red. Y eso, en otros sitios de la red, se considera "Trollear" y por ese mismo motivo no se banea del chat, si no que de toda la red.

Comment: Y gracias por tus palabras. Te he regañado alguna vez, pero en buenos terminos como a otros usuarios, y solo es para tratar de que entre todos mejoremos (me han regañado a mi, en mi posicion de mod, y tambien lo he sabido entender). Somos adultors. Una vulgaridad no nos va a espantar, pero un juego eterno a ver hasta donde llego, si.

Comment: O_o en que clase de universo paralelo vivimos donde regañan a @gbianchi.... Saludos :D