# Descripción del chat SOes y su reciente modificación

Tags: discusión, chat

Recientemente ha habido discusiones sobre el uso del lenguaje soez en el chat, sobre las normas del conducta del sitio y sobre las suspensiones por el uso de estas.

Debido a todo esto se ha cambiado la descripción del chat a una, **en mi opinión** bastante más restrictiva.

Antes teníamos algo como:

> Sala de chat de es.stackoverflow.com

Ahora [se ha cambiado a](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol):

> Programación y otras cosas de la comunidad de SO en español. En este chat tratamos de mantener un lenguaje cortés y respetuoso. Evitamos los modismos o regionalismos. Todas las personas son bienvenidas, mientras se comporten respetuosamente hacia sus pares. https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Se ha hablado que el objetivo del chat es que un usuario nuevo entre y se pueda sentir cómodo sea cual sea, yo con esto no me sentiría ni me siento cómodo.

- Como he dicho, es una descripción que te obliga a usar un *"lenguaje cortés"*

Tal y como está escrito, **parece** que se espera que todos nos hablemos de usted.

- Evitamos los modismos y regionalismos.

Siento que está fuera de lugar, la **mayoría** de personas mantienen respeto hacía los demás usuarios, modales básicos. Creo que esto queda implícito cuando hablas en un entorno como es el chat.

- *"mientras se comporten respetuosamente hacia sus pares."* es redundancia de *"tratamos de mantener un lenguaje cortés y respetuoso"*.

Comment: Yo pondría: *hablamos de todo un poco*

Comment: Preferiría que no apareceria en la descripción el concepto *lenguaje cortés* , a mi forma de ver, es un chat donde se pueden comentar problemas o charlar de forma distendida sobre diferentes temas variados.
Poner dichos conceptos, crean restricciones que dejan al chat sin su poca esencia que tiene cada día.

Comment: Bienvenida la discución... el cambio fue solo un cambio de aire, todo comentario sera bienvenido...

Comment: A mi me parece perfecto. Lo suyo sería que el que quiera proponga una frase, la ponga como respuesta y la gente vote, luego en una fecha que se decida se elige la más votada, así lo hicimos en Spanish al menos

Comment: Lo de _Evitamos los modismos o regionalismos_ me parece excesivo. Entiendo que todo surge por [una situación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4207/83) en la que se mezcló una palabra malsonante que en bastantes regiones suena horrible. Ahora, de aquí a directamente abogar por evitar regionalismos o modismo, creo que va un trecho. ¿No se puede decir "irse por las ramas"? ¿No puede decirse "estoy currando"? Como ejemplo de modismos y regionalismos sin maldad alguna.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Estoy de acuerdo en que la nueva descripción pudiese ser más restrictiva.

Omitiría la parte de "**Evitamos** los modismos o regionalismos.", ya que no todos modismos o regionalismos son una grosería o alguna mala palabra, pero tampoco dice "**Prohibido** usar modismos o regionalismos".

El único problema que veo con todo esto es que yo no sabría cuales son todos los modismos y/o regionalismos en otros países, sería algo sin sentido si dijera que los conozco todos, ¿como evitar algo que no sé lo que signifique para alguien más?

Fuera de eso, el lenguaje cortés en la sala de chat siempre ha existido, al menos desde mi punto de vista.

Dicho lo anterior, mi propuesta sería algo así:

> Chat de la comunidad de Stackoverflow en español. A veces charlemos sobre temas de programación, discutimos preguntas y/o respuestas, hablamos de tecnología y otras cosas. Habla, convive, conversa, responde, pregunta, pero siempre desde [el respeto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Comment: Estuve tentado a poner que en la sala de chat no hablamos ni mencionamos temas relacionados con Java 

Comment: Hey @Phi apoyo tu sugerencia!, pero no este comentario ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @Elenasys jaja, era una broma 

Comment: Ok @Phi  hahaha, saludos!

Comment: Yo no soy partidario de cargar demasiado una descripción, creo que lo ideal sería poder leerlo todo de un vistazo, esta está bien, pero es demasiado larga. De todos modos, solo es mi opinión.

Comment: @Aritzbn Comprendo tu punto de vista, y al igual que la mía, es una opinión más.

Comment: @Phi todo correcto, al final es una decisión que debe tomar toda la comunidad. de ahí que haya pedido a un moderador que convierta la publicación en wiki, desde ahora me desentiendo del tema. :)

Answer (score 0):

Por si acaso, a parte de poner mi propuesta en la pregunta, la pongo aquí a parte para que se cuenten los votos de la descripción para ponerla en la descripción del chat y **evitar confusiones entre la pregunta y la propuestas**.

> Chat oficial de [es.stackoverflow.com](https://es.stackoverflow.com/), hablamos de temas varios, pero sobre todo de programación y tecnología, siempre desde el respeto.

- Creo que es una descripción poco cargada.
- Es rápida de leer.
- Deja claro todo lo que hablamos en el chat.
- Se comenta el tema de ser respetuosos entre unos y otros.
- Tiene el enlace al sitio

Answer (score -2):

No cambiar la descripción, se quedaría como está ahora mismo:

> Programación y otras cosas de la comunidad de SO en español. En este
>   chat tratamos de mantener un lenguaje cortés y respetuoso. Evitamos
>   los modismos o regionalismos. Todas las personas son bienvenidas,
>   mientras se comporten respetuosamente hacia sus pares.
>   https://es.stackoverflow.com/